# Axios Bearer token

Tags: axios

I'm currently using the following code to acces to test my routes. I can acces the route but it always tells me that there's a error 401

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const HTTP = axios.create({
    baseURL: `http://localhost/rocourt/01-Backend/api/v1/public/`,
    headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer f4eaa1ff05046c01'
    }
});
```

It looks like that from the .vue

```
import {HTTP} from '../http-common';

    export default {
        name: 'adresse',
        data() {
            return {
                posts: [],
                errors: [],
                message: 'test'
            }
        },
        created() {
            HTTP.get(`adresses/1`)
                .then(response => {
                    this.posts = response.data;
                })
                .catch(e => {
                    this.errors.push(e)
                })
        }
    }
```

The errors looks like this :

[image: The errors looks like this]

Comment: You must set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials to true.. more info here https://www.sjoerdlangkemper.nl/2018/09/12/authorization-header-and-cors/

Comment: I tried to put     'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true   , into my HTTP const in the headers but it's still not working.

Comment: Did you add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * ` ?